# how can I remove broken spigot from garden hose end?

Tags: hose, gardening, connectors

I had a leak where my two way connector was attached to my garden hose so I tightened it up.  When I turned the water on, the male end of the two way broke off inside the female end of the garden hose.  I was wondering how I would go about getting it out, as I do not want to replace the hose.

Answer (score 4):

TRY a POTATO !
just cut a piece of potato and "screw" the potato into the female end-- it just might grab enough for you to unscrew the broke male threads --   it is safe on your hands and cheap to try - won't damage anything--  I have used this to get out broken light bulb parts in a socket too! GRANDPA taught me this decades ago!

Answer (score 2):

I got out my socket set and found one size that fit very snuggly in the sheared male end of the hose. For me, it was 17 mm. Banged it in there a little bit to make sure it was really snug and then set my socket wrench to loosen and it actually worked! I know the post is old, but I figure it might help somebody out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should try a pair of needle nosed pliers on it

Comment: Yes, I tried needle nose pliers, but could not get a grip on it

Comment: You may just have to get a little rough with it with a flat head screw driver and pliers, if its brass it will bend.

Comment: There is always a replacement hose end, cut off the broken end push the new end in and add the clamp. I use these all the time as horses and tractors are hard on hoses and it is cheaper to repair than replace

Comment: Backwards needle nose, aka **caliper pliers**.

Answer (score 0):

Since the cost of the tool to remove the piece would possibly cost as much as a new hose, see if you could borrow a pipe reamer

[image]

or inside pipe wrench

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cork from a wine bottle worked for me!  Very nice hose that I did not want to cut for any reason.  I had an orbit double connector break off inside of hose.  I tried the cork, pushed it in and twisted it out.  Good luck to anyone in the future with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Used the end of a small screwdriver and a bit of electrical tape wrapped around it to be a very tight fit. Turned it hard and it unscrewed and came out